# new ajax request on scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is javascript

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "not_data.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function my_func () {
               //show new name
            }
        });
      });
```

this is not_data.php

```
<?php

$name_query=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM  names");
        while($run_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($name_query)) {
            $name = $run_query['name'];

            echo $name;
}
?>
```

i want to call a new ajax request and get a new name from table names everytime user scrolls down

Comment: Be careful with binding ajax request to scroll, you might be launching lots of requests for each actual scroll.

Comment: i have a table of names and every time the user scrolls down i want to show for example 20 names . when he scrolls down again show 20 next name is table and so on

Comment: @RubenSerratePardo thanks i will change that as soon as it works for me :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You shouldn't use any `mysql_*` function any longer. All `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5. You should use `mysqli` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this excellent jquery plugin!

http://jscroll.com/

> jScroll is a jQuery plugin for infinite scrolling, written by Philip
>   Klauzinski. Infinite scrolling; also known as lazy loading, endless
>   scrolling, autopager, endless pages, etc.; is the ability to load
>   content via AJAX within the current page or content area as you scroll
>   down. The new content can be loaded automatically each time you scroll
>   to the end of the existing content, or it can be triggered to load by
>   clicking a navigation link at the end of the existing content.

Answer (score 0):

creat param for check loading state;
bind to scroll event
get two params

```
var top = $(this).scrollTop();
var height = $(this).height();
```

check scroll height

```
if (elHeight - top - height <= 50)
```

where elHeight - height of all element

and when it's true do your query

Answer (score 0):

Check If you have reached bottom and load more(send ajax call)

```
var win = $(window),
    doc = $(document);

win.scroll(function(){
    if( win.scrollTop() > doc.height() - win.height() ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "not_data.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function my_func (name) {
                $('<span>').html(name).appendTo('body')
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but i want to show names when i reach bottom ? can u help me ?

Comment: whats the response from not_data.php

Comment: <?php

$name_query=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM  names");
        while($run_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($name_query)) {
            $name = $run_query['name'];

            echo $name;
}
?> 

this man

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? there is a plugin out there that does exactly what you want. see my answer.

Comment: can anyone help me how to show a new $name variable when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "not_data.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (res) {
           // new name will be available in 'res' you can display in what way you like.
        }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: yes but how ? i have a variable $name in not_data.php how can i show when i reach the bottom ?

Comment: @anik kumar thanks man but i dont know how to show the name i have a variable $name in not_data.php how can i show it?

Comment: you can display using some html elements `$('<span>').html(res).appendTo('body')`

here i've taken `body` as an example you can set the desired element that you want to append.